# Installed fonts not appearing for WSL/Powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed a number of fonts with powershell via the powershell script in the following repository: https://github.com/powerline/fonts

Unfortunately, only a handful of my newly installed fonts seem to appear in the font selector when I right click on the WSL or Powershell window and select properties.

I can confirm that I have in fact installed all these fonts (they appear under font settings in windows), and I've restarted my system to no avail...

What's strange is that I was able to install the same set of fonts on a laptop running windows 10 about a week ago. I am now doing the exact same thing on a clean install of windows 10 and it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Exactly how are you installing the fonts? (terminal used, script used, etc)

Comment: Can you also check the permissions and users on the installed fonts? Compare that with the fonts that work and weren't installed by you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, It works for me in Windows Terminal as well as in MobaXterm. Tried below given font to fix icon missing issue.

====================

- MesloLGS NF
- RobotoMono NF
- Delugia Nerd Font

====================

Download link for Font:

1. https://github.com/romkatv/dotfiles-public/blob/master/.local/share/fonts/NerdFonts/MesloLGS%20NF%20Regular.ttf
2. https://github.com/google/fonts/raw/master/apache/robotomono/RobotoMono%5Bwght%5D.ttf
3. https://github.com/adam7/delugia-code/releases/download/v2009.14/Delugia.Nerd.Font.Complete.ttf

Hope it Helps!!